# Ruby IMAP library doesn't decode mail subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imap, quoted-printable

I have got mail message with following subject in my Gmail accout:

"400, значение, значение"

Here is the code I use to grab mail:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true, nil, false)
imap.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD) 
imap.select("INBOX")
messages = imap.search(['ALL']).map do |message_id|
  msg =imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  result =  {:mailbox => msg.from[0].mailbox, :host => msg.from[0].host, :subject => msg.subject, :created_at => msg.date}
  imap.store(message_id, "+FLAGS", [:Deleted])
  result
end
imap.expunge()
imap.logout
```

In msg.subject i've got following value "=?KOI8-R?B?MTAwLCDixc7ayc4sIDMwMDAgzMnU0s/X?="

It seems that IMAP haven't decoded it. Should I do I manually or IMAP library could it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using NKF?

```
require 'nkf'
...
result =  {... :subject => NKF.nkf("-mw", msg.subject), ...}
```

-mw means MIME decode and utf-8 output

Answer (score 10):

Mail::Encodings is really helpful here:

```
require 'mail'
test = "zwei plus =?ISO-8859-15?Q?zw=F6lf_ist_vierzehn?="
puts Mail::Encodings.value_decode(test)
```

returns

```
zwei plus zwölf ist vierzehn
```

Comment: This code saved my one day effort of Google search. Awesoem!